# how to delete row value having foreign key in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have 2 tables:

URL_table
`| link_id | link_url|` <=== schema

user_table
`| link_id | is_visited |` <==== schema


When i want to delete a value in user_table,
 and my input is `link_url`,
 i have to resolve the `link_id` first from URL_table

```
select link_id from URL_table where link_url="www.example.com"
```

and then

```
delete from user_table where link_id='....
```

since link_id is a foreign key in URL table, 
 is there a way i can do this in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

```
delete u
from user_table u
join url_table l on l.link_id = u.link_id
where l.link_url = 'www.example.com"'
```